# translations UX: include colon etc.?

Tags: translation, user-experience

I'm solving little UX problem. I'm marking texts in our app and then the texts are given to some people for translation.

I want to knouw your opinion what way would be better to use:

Text in app is e.g. " ***Serial number:*** "

1. Do I have to give for translation whole text including the colon at the end
2. or give just the string *Serial number* without the colon?

People sometimes forget to write the colon into the translation.

But then there are texts like " ***Please, send the device to our address:*** ", where it could look weird without the colon at the end. Someone then can complete the translation with a dot added at the end.

What you suggest?

Comment: While things like colon might not matter, other punctuation character might be different in different languages. For example, a simple question is followed by a single question-mark in many languages, but not Spanish where the whole sentence have to start with an upside-down question-mark. So my advice is to include punctuation.

Comment: I agree with Joachim. You should include the ponctuation. In French, we must put a space before the colon (also before the semi-colons and question/exclamation marks), but in English not. So it should be part of your translation, unless you have another mechanism to add it automatically (e.g. in your GUI toolkit).

Comment: hmm, thank you for learning me some new interesting facts. I'll use them.

Comment: Did you forget about the bounty? ***https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729443/google-sign-in-button-how-to-get-id-token-on-server-when-using-redirect-flow/51944838#51944838***